# Can we redo a plugin published on wordpress.org and disable update for the user who has it already installed on there site

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have the plugin on wordpress.org I want to redo that plugin, but when I redo that plugin it will be the same plugin but I can't migrate old plugin user to this new plugin, so I want to disable the update for the old users of this plugin so they continue to use the old plugin (and migrate on their own risk) but it should not auto update for them

Answer (score 0):

You can change the plugin version in `wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/your-plugin.php` to something like:

```php
 * Version: 9999
```

Every plugin has comments at the start of the plugin's file that gives wordpress information. e.g

```php
/**
 * Plugin Name: the name of the plugin
 * Plugin URI: https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin
 * Description: blah blah
 * Version: 9999
 * Author: author etc
**/
```

By adding version 9999 wordpress thinks that your plugin is updated so it wont be shown as a plugin that needs update.

Hope this trick helps you.

Comment: I am the developer of that plugin (i don't have to disable it on my website), it is like the new version data structure will be completely different from the old one so I want to know can I di something in WordPress repository so whoever have the old version they stay with old version and new version will be different only for the new installer